# Can't figure out Delayed::DeserializationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am running delayed_job 3.0.5 (delayed_job_active_record 0.4.1) with Rails 3.2.12.  I am having problems with some of my jobs failing because of "Deserialization".  Here is a really simple example of one of the failing handlers:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod
object: LOAD;Project;924951
method: :send_project_open_close_without_delay
args: []
```

When I try to invoke this job:

```
Delayed::DeserializationError: Job failed to load: undefined method `members' for nil:NilClass.
```

Everyone seems to think this is caused by an AR object that no longer exists.  In my case, I can run the handler just fine:

```
Project.find(924951).send_open_close_without_delay
```

What else could be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone ever runs into this issue.  I figured out the cause was some of the jobs were injected with an older version of Delayed Job.  So when the newer Delayed Job attempted to process them, it was unable to deserialize the handler.

Comment: I stopped my delayed job processes that were started on an older version and deleted the old jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I also experienced this issue when we upgrade to rails 3.2.  The error I got was caused by the yaml handler used by delayed job.  Try adding the following to `config/boot.rb`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried it, but still get the same error?

Comment: if you restarted delayed job after adding this, i'm out of ideas.  check for any part of your code that calls `members` :)

Comment: Yeah, I have NOTHING that references "members".  I opened a ticket with delayed_job and hope its a bug they can fix.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an upgrade to `Delayed::Job` that changed the serialization handler AND changed the type of object used for `PerformableMethod`. If you want to fix all old jobs and stick with the new defaults for Delayed::Job, you can fix failing ones with this query:

```
Delayed::Job.where('failed_at is not null').each do |dj|
  dj.handler = dj.handler.gsub('struct:Delayed', 'object:Delayed')
  Delayed::Worker.new.run(dj)
end
```

The change occurred around here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/7b8a79a72c0ee5d8bac4bc0b183d1cce9cedff85

Making `PerformableMethod` a class instead of a `Struct`.