# DelayedJob error following upgrade to Rails 4: Delayed::DeserializationError: Job failed to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I'm part way through upgrading a Rails app from 3.2 to 4.x. I now get the following littered through my tests.

```
Delayed::DeserializationError:
   Job failed to load: no implicit conversion of nil into String. Handler: nil
```

In my config/environments/test.rb I have delayed job set to:

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```

so I'm not actually expecting DelayedJob to actually do anything. The error is raised the first time a method is delayed.

Comment: Are you using the gem `protected_attributes`? If so, you need to call it **before** the `delayed_job` gem. This was the solution to me. It was also a terrible lack of attention since they have it in the README: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-4

Answer (score 0):

Is this because you have delayed_jobs that were created before the upgrade?

I had this issue:
[Can't figure out Delayed::DeserializationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892232/cant-figure-out-delayeddeserializationerror)